# How to top text element to top border?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm [trying](https://jsfiddle.net/2sm1w8d4/) to adjust some svg text to touch the top of red rectangle border. I've used attribute  **alignment-baseline**: `top` but it's not working.

How do I move text to the top?

My current code looks like:

```
<text alignment-baseline="top" x="400" y="319" fill="#cf1616" font-size="35px" style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; cursor: pointer;">TEXT</text>
```

Comment: Where is the SVG? Also in the fiddle is only the text element...

Comment: No matter. I have added svg. This is absolute position

Comment: Please fix your SVG so that it displays something.

Comment: Fixed, check out

Comment: It's not fixed. By removing the `<svg>` tags, you've just turned it into an HTML unknown element, which causes the browser to display it as HTML text, not an SVG.  The reason the text wasn't showing before was because the text position was outside the the edge of the SVG canvas, which defaults to 300x150 if no size is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alignment-baseline: top` is not the one you want.  The one you probably want is `alignment-baseline: hanging`.  That positions the text so it is hanging below the `y` position that you specify.

```css
svg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="200">
  <text alignment-baseline="hanging" x="100" y="0" fill="gold" font-size="35px" style="font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; cursor: pointer;">пвапвап</text>
</svg>
```

But be aware that the `alignment-baseline` requires that the font file has the necessary font table in it.  As long as you are sure that the font(s) that will be used (including fallback fonts) have the table, then this is a safe method to use.

Also note that `hanging` usually means hanging *from the top of capital letters*.  Your text only has lower case letters.  That's why there is a little gap above the letters in this example.

Answer (score 0):

[See the documentation:>>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)

[See the alignment-baseline documentation:>>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline)

```css
svg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="120" viewBox="0 0 300 120"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
    text { 
      font-size: 35px; 
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <text alignment-baseline="baseline"
          x="60" y="110" fill="#cf1616">A baseline</text>
</svg>
```